# Retrieve company name with ticker symbol input, yahoo or google API

Tags: python, json, yahoo-finance, stock, google-finance-api

Just looking for a simple api return, where I can input a ticker symbol and receive the full company name:

ticker('MSFT')
will return
"Microsoft"

Comment: Uhh... What have you tried?

Comment: I looked through a bunch of previous answers onsite and couldn't find anything current.

Comment: What code have you tried writing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to first find a website / API which allows you to lookup stock symbols and provide information. Then you can query that API for information.

I came up with a quick and dirty solution here:

```
import requests


def get_symbol(symbol):
    symbol_list = requests.get("http://chstocksearch.herokuapp.com/api/{}".format(symbol)).json()

    for x in symbol_list:
        if x['symbol'] == symbol:
            return x['company']


company = get_symbol("MSFT")

print(company)
```

This website only provides company name. I didn't put any error checks. And you need the `requests` module for it to work. Please install it using `pip install requests`.

**Update:** Here's the code sample using Yahoo! Finance API:

```
import requests


def get_symbol(symbol):
    url = "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query={}&region=1&lang=en".format(symbol)

    result = requests.get(url).json()

    for x in result['ResultSet']['Result']:
        if x['symbol'] == symbol:
            return x['name']


company = get_symbol("MSFT")

print(company)
```

Comment: Is it possible to return Ticker symbol given the name of the company? Which parameters should I modify in your code?

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 18):

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

company_name = msft.info['longName']

#Output = 'Microsoft Corporation'
```

So this way you would be able to get the full names of companies from stock symbols

Comment: I love yfinance and use it regularly. Unfortunately it seems that the info method is somewhat flaky, depending on the stock your working with. Some of the other suggestions above seem to be from the days when the Yahoo and Google APIs were still functioning.

Comment: Actually this answer does not work appropriately for all tickers. For example, the ticker OGEN (which is Oragenics, Inc) gives the following error: 

IndexError: list index out of range

I guess it's just that yfinance is not up-to-date. Also, if you gibe a non-existent ticker, e.g. "--", it throws a ValueError:

ValueError: No tables found

When, ideally it I would expect something along the lines of None.

Comment: The script returns me the error '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 5
      1 import yfinance as yf
      3 msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
----> 5 company_name = msft.info['longName']

KeyError: 'longName'

Answer (score 5):

Using fuzzy match to get company symbol from company name or vice versa

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import requests

def getCompany(text):
    r = requests.get('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols')
    stockList = r.json()
    return process.extractOne(text, stockList)[0]


getCompany('GOOG')
getCompany('Alphabet')
```

Comment: That API doesn't appear to be available any longer - a 403 is returned on request.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how to get the stock price of a company using its name rather than its symbol

```
import yfinance as yf

def getStock(search_term):
    results = []
    query = requests.get(f'https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/autocomplete?region=IN&lang=en&query={search_term}', 
    headers={
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'X-API-KEY': 'API_KEY'
    })
    response = query.json()
    for i in response['ResultSet']['Result']:
        final = i['symbol']
        results.append(final)

    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(results[0])
        price = stock.info["regularMarketPrice"]
        full_name = stock.info['longName']
        curreny = stock.info["currency"]
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something went wrong')

return f"The stock price of {full_name} is {price} {curreny}"

stock = input("Enter the company's name: ")
final = getStock(stock)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
Enter the company's name: Apple
The stock price of Apple Inc. is 172.39 USD
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a function the takes the company's name, not ticker, here's a really simple one.

It uses a Yahoo Finance endpoint to return a ticker, given a name. Additionally, it requires no API key.

```
import requests

def get_ticker (company_name):
    url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search"
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
    params = {"q": company_name, "quotes_count": 1, "country": "United States"}

    res = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
    data = res.json()

    company_code = data['quotes'][0]['symbol']
    return company_code
```

For the [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652558/14503336), replace it with what you please or keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Yahoo API call. @masnun's call will return all results that contain the search param, for example trying AMD (Advanced Micro Devices):
`http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=amd&region=1&lang=en`
gives you `AMD (Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.), AMDA (Amedica Corporation), DOX (Amdocs Limited),` etc.

If you know the ticker, you can try either of these Yahoo APIs:z
`http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=amd&f=nb4t8` (well documented, this particular call asks for n=name; b4=book value; t8=1yr target price).
`https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/amd` (not very well documented but new...see more info here about this API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40243903/933972)

Forgot to include the Google API, which seems ok for stock quotes, but not reliable for full data on option chains:
'https://www.google.com/finance?q=nyse:amd&output=json'

Answer (score 0):

I use Quandl for prices, so when I had a similar issue I decided to check there. If you go to https://www.quandl.com/data/EOD-End-of-Day-US-Stock-Prices/documentation about a quarter of the way down under Available Tickers there is a link to download a csv file containing names and tickers. I then use the following code to create a dictionary with ticker as key and name a value.

```
def companyNames():
    cnames = pd.read_csv('ticker_list.csv')
    cnames_dict = pd.Series(cnames.Name.values, index=cnames.Ticker).to_dict()
    
    return cnames_dict
```