# Extract number of the institutional holding that a stock has

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, extract, yfinance

I'm trying to extract the number of the institutional holding that a stock has.

For instance, here from Apple at the following link

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/holders?p=AAPL)

#### Extract a number

I would like to get the number `5,102` from:

```
 "institutionsCount": {
    "raw": 5102,
    "fmt": "5.1k",
    "longFmt": "5,102"
}
```

I think this is a tulip right?

#### Code

This is the code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/holders?p=AAPL'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

#### What I tried

I tried to use `yfinance` but I don't know how to make a loop to extract all the holders for each ticker. So I though would be more easy to do a web scraping for one and then looping for each stock.

Comment: Do you need beautifulsoup? - https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Comment: And what do you mean by "tulip"? That's a flower

Comment: Did you do research, e.g. [example using `yfinance`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967533/retrieve-company-name-with-ticker-symbol-input-yahoo-or-google-api/40244249#40244249) ?

Comment: I tried to use yfinance but I don't know how to make a loop to extract all the holders for each ticker. So I though would be more easy to do a web scraping for one and then looping for each stock. But apparently I was wrong :(

Comment: @SantiGil web-scraping not only cumbersome, but also often forbidden by _Terms and Conditions_ or the [Robots-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). That's why developers spent effort in writing a module like `yfinance`. Present your attempts with yfinance and we can help you on the last-mile. But please [edit] your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `yfinance`

Try the module [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) (an API facade, client library to Yahoo! Finance). Some research here on SO shows how:

- [Retrieve company name with ticker symbol input, yahoo or google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967533/retrieve-company-name-with-ticker-symbol-input-yahoo-or-google-api/40244249#40244249)

Then adjust to your case and play around:

```
import yfinance as yf

stock = yf.Ticker('APPL')
print(stock.info)
```

Prints the retrieved JSON data `stock.info` as a dict:

```
{'symbol': 'APPL', 'quoteType': 'MUTUALFUND', 'exchange': 'YHD', 'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York', 'exchangeTimezoneShortName': 'EST', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds': '-18000000', 'market': 'us_market', 'isEsgPopulated': False, 'quoteSourceName': 'Delayed Quote', 'regularMarketOpen': None, 'averageDailyVolume3Month': None, 'regularMarketTime': 1561759658, 'volume24Hr': None, 'regularMarketDayHigh': None, 'shortName': None, 'averageDailyVolume10Day': None, 'longName': None, 'regularMarketChange': None, 'regularMarketPreviousClose': None, 'preMarketPrice': None, 'exchangeDataDelayedBy': 0, 'toCurrency': None, 'postMarketChange': None, 'postMarketPrice': None, 'exchangeName': 'YHD', 'preMarketChange': None, 'circulatingSupply': None, 'regularMarketDayLow': None, 'priceHint': 2, 'regularMarketPrice': None, 'regularMarketVolume': None, 'lastMarket': None, 'regularMarketSource': 'DELAYED', 'openInterest': None, 'marketState': 'POST', 'underlyingSymbol': None, 'marketCap': None, 'volumeAllCurrencies': None, 'strikePrice': None, 'maxAge': 1, 'fromCurrency': None, 'logo_url': ''}
```

However, there is no `institution` or any other count resembling your information-demand (given number `5,102`) like on the screenshot from Yahoo! Finance page of AAPL:
[image: Yahoo! Finance page of AAPL, clipping with institutions count]

#### Research on the desired figure

I searched the web for `Number of Institutions Holding Shares` and  `yfinance` and found an article explaining it:

- Medium: [All you need to know about yfinance : Yahoo! Finance Library | by Abhijith Chandradas | Nerd For Tech](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/all-you-need-to-know-about-yfinance-yahoo-finance-library-fa4c6e48f08e)

> `Ticker.major_holders` and `Ticker.institutional_holders` can be used to get details of shareholding of the company.
>
> `major_holders`: shows how much of the shares and float are held by the insiders and institutions
>
> `Ticker.institutional_holders` provides the details of major institutioal shareholding.

#### Retrieve information about *holders* using `yfinance`

```
import yfinance as yf

appl = yf.Ticker('APPL')

full_name = appl.info['longName']
major_holders = appl.major_holders
institutional_holders = appl.institutional_holders

print(f"Name:\n{full_name}")
print(f"Major holders:\n{major_holders}")
print(f"Institutional holders:\n{institutional_holders}")
```

Prints what is expected to hold the desired number:

```
Name:
None
Major holders:
                         0   1
0           Previous Close NaN
1               YTD Return NaN
2      Expense Ratio (net) NaN
3                 Category NaN
4            Last Cap Gain NaN
5       Morningstar Rating NaN
6  Morningstar Risk Rating NaN
7    Sustainability Rating NaN
Institutional holders:
                      0   1
0            Net Assets NaN
1     Beta (5Y Monthly) NaN
2                 Yield NaN
3     5y Average Return NaN
4     Holdings Turnover NaN
5         Last Dividend NaN
6  Average for Category NaN
7        Inception Date NaN
```

Now it is left to you to figure out, why there is no data available for `APPL`.

Test also the ticker symbol `AMZN` and see if the example outputs from Medium article can be reproduced with figures available ️

#### Parsing JSON an extracting a value

Given you have this JSON:

```json
 "institutionsCount": {
    "raw": 5102,
    "fmt": "5.1k",
    "longFmt": "5,102"
}
```

Then you can parse it using Pythons standard module `json`:

```
import json

json_text = """
 "institutionsCount": {
    "raw": 5102,
    "fmt": "5.1k",
    "longFmt": "5,102"
}
"""
obj = json.loads('{'+json_text+'}')  # surrounding braces needed to make it a valid JSON (object)
print(obj['institutionsCount']['longFmt'])
# 5,102
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to all for the inspiration. As hc_dev mention, would be better to use the module of yfinance. Since yfinance gives you a pandas.core.frame, I transform it to a list, so I can grab what I wanted. So I think the following would solve the problem efficiently.

**CODE**

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker = input('Enter ticker:')
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
holders = stock.major_holders
holders_list = holders[0].to_list()
number = holders_list[3]
print('Number of institutionals:', number)
```