# Retrieving option chains from the Yahoo Finance API

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to retrieve but I cannot manage to get it to retrieve data.
The query I am using is: `SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.options WHERE symbol="AAPL"`

So that you can try: [Yahoo Finance API](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.options%20where%20%20symbol%3D%22TSLA%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&=#h=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.options%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%22AAPL%22)

Is there any other good and reliable source for option chains that I can retrieve easily with some `Scala` code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common question. Since the remake of finance.yahoo.com many API and scraping tools are broken. This API is working and has been for the past month+ without incidence.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40243903/933972

Not sure about Scala, but I'm using it with the JSON return in my MeteorJS framework.

The old tried-and-true API still works:
'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=amd&f=nb4t8' (well documented, this particular call asks for n=name; b4=book value; t8=1yr target price).

Comment: As of January 2018, the "tried and true" Yahoo API no longer works.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working

Comment: That is true. Now that $AABA is the owner of Yahoo, things have changed. This query still works, as noted in the above SO link:  https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/amd
 This returns not only options, but the 'quote' node with many data points like current price, 52-weeks, marketCap, forwardPE, etc.